# Bootstrap Umbraco menu Dropdown click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, umbraco

I work for a site which has a site which is built upon Umbraco and utilizes bootstrap and Jquery.

We have a top navigation menu which has pages and sub-pages. When you hover over a navigation menu it opens up the sub-menu and lets you go to them.

When this menu is viewed on a mobile device it becomes a hamburger and when you click on it it drop-down and the main tabs are shown. Here when you click on the main tab it shows the sub-menu quickly but then goes to the main tab instead of allowing you to click on the sub-menu.

The problem is that this is a large site which is about to launch so that there is no easy way to find what links to what. What is a elegant way to fix this?

I cannot provide the link due to the fact that it is a company.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this bit of JS (requires jQuery):

```
$(".dropdown").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or you could change your menu partial to just not put the URL in for menu items that have a dropdown and instead put a # in its place.